# Python list not printing as desired

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list, which is obtained as an output from a separate Python regex part of the code. The list is as follows:

```
v = [['-0.00162439495203', '-0.000178892778126']]
```

I am trying to convert this to string and write to a file as

```
v_new = ','.join(map(str, v))
f.write('%s\n'%v_new)
f.close
```

However, when I open my file instead of having

```
-0.00162439495203
-0.000178892778126
```

I get `['-0.00162439495203', '-0.000178892778126']`, that is, including the `[] and ''` and in the same line. Note the file `f` is opened for writing else where, which is not shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the element of v, a string will print without the brackets and quotes. Like so:

```
v = [['-0.00162439495203']]
v_new = ','.join(map(str, v[0]))
```

Which is very close to what you have.

EDIT: something like this could work too.

```
v = [['-0.00162439495203', '-0.000178892778126']]
v_new = ','.join(v[0])   
v_new = v_new.replace(',','\n')
```

Comment: Thanks @KyleBooth. But the values are writing as comma separated than writing onto new line. Anything wrong with this `f.write("%s\n" %v_new)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a list within a list, which contains a string. When you join, you only join on the outer list (which joins one element, which is the inner list). You want to join on the inner list. Like so:

```
print(','.join(v[0]))
```

The elements in the inner list are already strings, so there's no need to map the str function onto them.

Comment: Thanks again, @Andew. `print(','.join(v[0]))` works, however, when I write to a file using `\n` it doesn't print into two separate lines, rather separated by a `,` such as `-0.00162439495203,-0.000178892778126`. This is what I did: `v_new = ','.join(v[0])` followed by `f.write("%s\n" %v_new)`

Comment: Please look up the documentation on the string.join() call. For a quick answer, it simply creates one string out of the elements in the list, seperated by the string. So in your case, it will create one string, with each element in the list separated by ','